# Is there a good React-Native option for paginating a large html file into a stack of adaptive screen components that the user could swipe through?

Tags: react-native, pagination, logic, mobile-application, epub.js

The react native App I am building needs a feature where the user can read a six thousand word booklet within the application. I would like it to have a similar user experience to reading an E-book on the kindle or apple books app. My original plan was to convert it to EPUB and use an Epub reader component package to bring in that feature. I have yet to find a react native or expo package that is being actively maintained. That option seems like over-kill for a single small booklet.

Since I just need one fairly small booklet now and dont anticipate more than a few small booklets added in the future, I am ok with doing a little bit of adjustment to the Html to get it styled right. I have converted it from a google doc to an HTML file containing 110 `<p>` elements.
Do you have any suggestions on how to automatically paginate all the `<p>` elements so that they fit on a flexible stack of pages without scroll view?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried the Epub.js javascript library (https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/)?